# How to send a message to SNS topic through the test event of an AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an AWS lambda function that triggers an SNS topic on failure.

[image]

I'm wondering why the SNS topic is not triggered why I run "Test" in the AWS console.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, the python lambda function raises an error at line 4.

I've subscribed to the SNS topic with my e-mail address. And I have clicked the "Confirm subscription" link. So there should be no problem receiving messages from the SNS topic.

I've also confirmed that the role of my AWS lambda function has "AmazonSNSFullAccess" permission.

Why can't I trigger SNS topic through the "Test" in AWS lambda function?

Comment: Test in the AWS Lambda console will be a synchronous invoke, it needs to be an [asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) failure as the source to invoke the SNS topic

Comment: @pyzor Thank you for your reminder. In the end, I use boto3 to asynchronousely invoke the lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to pyzor's information, I use the following python script to asynchronously trigger my AWS lambda function so that it can send messages to SNS topic.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='my-function',
    InvocationType='Event'
)
print(f"response: {response}")
```